# Is this formula related to the energy function / boltzmann distribution?

Tags: time-series, probability, graphical-model, latent-class

I am reading [research done in this thesis](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/85399). On page 20-21 (section 2.1) of the thesis, it describes the following stochastic model:

> ... let us focus for the rest of this chapter on
>   time-varying signals ... In this context,
>   an observed object is simply a signal in a time window of a certain length. A latent
>   source object may be thought of as a signal corresponding to a prototypical type of
>   event. If the same type of event were to happen many times, we suppose that the
>   resulting observed signals are noisy versions of the latent source signal corresponding
>   to that type of event.
>
> We say an observation $s$ from an infinite stream $s_{\infty}$, is *generated* by a latent source
>   $q$ if $s$ is a noisy version of $q$. Accordingly, we propose the following stochastic model
>   relating a latent source $q$ and an observation $s$:
>   $$P(s \text{ generated by } q) \propto \text{exp}(-\gamma d(s,q))$$
>
> where $d(s, q)$ is the distance between $s$ and $q$ and $-\gamma$ is a scaling parameter.

I had never seen this formula before, and [after looking around, I think it may be related to a potential function](https://medium.com/@neerajsharma_28983/intuitive-guide-to-probability-graphical-models-be81150da7a), whose representation is the Boltzmann distribution. There is a picture on page 23 of the thesis depicting what seems like different *potential* values.

Am I correct? Any other insights/references are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The Boltzmann distribution is not only a different expression (it shares the exponential term, but so do many other distributions), but also a much different mechanism that generates the distribution (The Boltzmann distribution is more like related to a combinatorics problem relating probability of an event, observing some energy or energy distribution, to the size/density of the set of points in the sample space with that energy distribution).

The distribution that you have, when using the squared distance $d (s,q) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{obs}} (s_i-q_i)^2 $ looks more like a multivariate Gaussian distribution.

When you substitute that term then the equation becomes:
$$P(s \text{ generated by } q) \propto \prod_{i=1}^{N_{obs}} \text{exp}(-\gamma (s_i-q_i)^2)$$

I haven't read much more from that thesis but it looks like some sort of generalization of [k-means clustering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or [mixture model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Multivariate_Gaussian_mixture_model).

Comment: this looks like some kind of a kernel method

Comment: I am not sure how you connect the euclidean distance formula with the multivariate Gaussian distribution. Also, I looked into some online k-means clustering and I didn't see any references that seemed similar, can you provide one that does?

Comment: @guy A multivariate distribution can be related to the Euclidean distance by considering a geometrical interpretation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Geometric_interpretation

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I did some further looking into and I've come to the conclusion that this is a spin on the radial basis function. Since this is related to SVM kernels, k-means clustering, and other critical topics, it is confusing that the authors never mentioned this.